# 500 Error Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a Preferences landing page created in Cloud Pages for our B2C customers that works fine. I am trying to replicate for another division and running into issues. I am able to publish it without error and click the url in cloud pages however, when I place in my email footer and link to the cloud page, I get a 500 error. I have copied the ampscript below as well as the html for the footer. Can any help? I have been staring at this for 2 days and cant figure it out.

```
%%[
set @IdCheck = QueryParameter('id')

if empty(@IdCheck) then
  set @Id = _subscriberkey 
else
  set @Id = QueryParameter('id')
endif

SET @Rows = LookupRows('CG_Preferences','EmailAddress',@Id)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Rows) > 0 THEN
SET @EmailAddress = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1), 'EmailAddress')
SET @CG_Prefences = FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1), 'CorporateGifts')
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
SET @Rows2 = LookupRows('B2C_Contact_Data','EmailAddress',@Id)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Rows2) > 0 THEN
SET @EmailAddress = FIELD(ROW(@Rows2,1), 'EmailAddress')
SET @first = FIELD(ROW(@Rows2,1), 'First_Name')
SET @last = FIELD(ROW(@Rows2,1), 'Last_Name')
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
SET @Rows3 = LookupRows('B2C Contact Address Data','EmailAddress',@Id)
IF ROWCOUNT(@Rows3) > 0 THEN
SET @EmailAddress = FIELD(ROW(@Rows3,1), 'EmailAddress')
SET @CountryName = FIELD(ROW(@Rows3,1), 'Country_Name')
SET @StateName = FIELD(ROW(@Rows3,1), 'State_Province_Name')
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
var @EmailAddress, @CorporateGiftsBoo
set @EmailAddress = RequestParameter('email')
set @Language = RequestParameter('language')
set @firstname = RequestParameter('firstname')
set @lastname = RequestParameter('lastname')
set @Country = RequestParameter('Country')
set @State = RequestParameter('State')
IF RequestParameter('CorporateGifts') == "on" THEN
SET @CorporateGiftsBoo = 'True'
ELSE
SET @CorporateGiftsBoo = 'False'
ENDIF
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("unsub") == true THEN
Set @FalseBoo = 'False'
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Corporate_Gifts", @FalseBoo, "Email_Date_Unsubscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status", @Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("sub") == true THEN
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Email_Date_Subscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status",
@Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("demographic") == true THEN
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "CorporateGifts", @CorporateGiftsBoo, "Language", @Language)
UpsertDE('B2C_Contact_Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'First_Name', @firstname, 'Last_Name', @lastname)
UpsertDE('B2C Contact Address Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'Country_Name', @Country, 'State_Province_Name',
@State)
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
SET @CorporateGiftsChecked = IIF(@CorporateGifts == True, "checked", "")
]%%
%%[
SET @contactId = _subscriberkey
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("unsub") == true THEN
/* log unsubscribe event to mark as unsubscribed in All Subscribers */
SET @reason = "Unsubscribed through custom subscription center"
SET @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
SETObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")
SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @contactId)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
SET @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
SETObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
SET @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("sub") == true THEN
/* set subscriber status to active in All Subscribers */
SET @email = RequestParameter("email")
SET @Subscriber = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "SubscriberKey", @contactId)
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "EmailAddress", @SubscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber, "Status", "Active" )
SET @Status = InvokeUpdate(@Subscriber, @createErrDesc, @createErrNo, @createOpts)
ENDIF
]%%
%%[
set @Status1 = Lookup("_Subscribers", "Status" , "SubscriberKey", @contactId)
]%%
```

**HTML for the Email pointing to the cloud page**

```
&nbsp;</div>%%[ if 0 == 1 then ]%%%%profile_center_url%%%%[endif]%%<div>
                  <a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="cloudpageslandingpage" href="%%=CloudPagesURL(491)=%%" style="color:#525252;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="Manage Preferences "><span style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#525252;">Manage Preferences</span></span></a></div><div>
                  <br>
```

Comment: What do you get when you copy the link to the CloudPage _from your inbox_ and paste it into [wheregoes.com](https://wheregoes.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment- this is not the correct answer but a "shot in the dark" / "please specify"/ "ways to improve your question to to help us help you" post.

some general remarks:

a) We also see a wall of code. Introduce indentation to better visualize and logical entities.

```
*/ not great*/

IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("unsub") == true THEN
Set @FalseBoo = 'False'
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Corporate_Gifts", @FalseBoo, "Email_Date_Unsubscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status",@Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("sub") == true THEN
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Email_Date_Subscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status",@Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("demographic") == true THEN
UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "CorporateGifts", @CorporateGiftsBoo, "Language", @Language)
UpsertDE('B2C_Contact_Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'First_Name', @firstname, 'Last_Name', @lastname)
UpsertDE('B2C Contact Address Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'Country_Name', @Country, 'State_Province_Name',@State)
ENDIF
```

```
/*better:*/
IF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("unsub") == true THEN
    Set @FalseBoo = 'False'
    UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Corporate_Gifts", @FalseBoo, "Email_Date_Unsubscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status", @Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("sub") == true THEN
    UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "Email_Date_Subscribed", Now(), "Email_Subscription_Status",
@Status1)
ELSEIF RequestParameter("submitted") == true AND RequestParameter("demographic") == true THEN
    UpsertDE("Preferences",1,"EmailAddress", @EmailAddress, "CorporateGifts", @CorporateGiftsBoo, "Language", @Language)
    UpsertDE('B2C_Contact_Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'First_Name', @firstname, 'Last_Name', @lastname)
    UpsertDE('B2C Contact Address Data', 1, 'EmailAddress', @EmailAddress, 'Country_Name', @Country, 'State_Province_Name',
@State)
ENDIF
```

(the first IF clause does it right).

b) even with that, it's a lot of stuff.

isolate the error source through the infamous wolf-fence debugging: http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2008/12/wolf-fence-debugging.html - take out parts of code, try if it now works. if yes, the error is in the part you took out, else in the other part. Leave working parts out of your question, that'll narrow it down enough for stackExchange to help meaningfully. Also, maybe there are multiple problems? This way you'll tackle them one by one.

c) after finding the error - use consistent variables names; @id, @contactId, @IdCheck ... they seem to all be pretty much the same.

specific to your error:

The link in the email uses cloudPagesURL() function - that would change the incoming data as opposed to "clicking the raw url", and fits your your "works one way, doesn't work the other way" description.

Then the (first) error would already be fenced to here, if the `@Id` variable doesn't come out right, nothing else will work right:

```
%%[
set @IdCheck = QueryParameter('id')

if empty(@IdCheck) then
  set @Id = _subscriberkey 
else
  set @Id = QueryParameter('id')
endif
]%% id: %%=v(@id)=%%
<br>idCheck:  %%=v(@IdCheck)=%%
```

e) I output the key variables to get you started wolf-fencing. Try the above with both ways of accessing the page, compare the results. if it is confusing I'm sure we can help :)

Typical scenario: If you click the email link but `@Id` comes out empty -  Ensure that the subscriber you are clicking the link for is on all subscribers list. If that subscriber is not on All Subscribers List, _subscriber evaluates to empty.

Send an actual email to your test address (the sendout adds it to all subscribers) to be sure.

Comment: Cut out code until it works and then go back one step.  You found the issue.

Comment: And, seriously, is indentation a super-power?